# Purchase movies from US store using itunes giftcard

Tags: itunes-store, movie

I would like to know whether I can buy movies from the iTunes store using just a US iTunes account and an iTunes gift card (purchased in the US), in a different country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can buy anything. Your appleid must have a US address. I use an Apple store address ;-)